# db.all function doesn't return as an array variable

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, json, express

I want to receive an array from db.all function in order to use it in my custom JSON object that I want to return it as a response

I have tried 
Object.values(members);
members.fulfillmentValue;
some PROMISE methods I found in StackOverFlow

```js
app.get('/group/:groupId', (req, res, next) => {

    const members= db.all('SELECT name,active FROM members WHERE groupId = ?;', req.params.groupId);

    return db.get('SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groups.id = ?;',req.params.groupId)
     .then(group =>  res.json({
         group.name,
         members:[members]
        }))
        .catch(next);
});
```

actual response

```
{
   "name":"group 1",
   "memebers":[
      {"isFulfilled":true,"isRejected":false,"fulfillmentValue":[
         {"name":"Member 1","active":1},
         {"name":"Member 2","active":0}
      ]
   }]
}
```

expected response

```
{
   "name":"group 1",
   "memebers":[
      {"name":"Member 1","active":1},
      {"name":"Member 2","active":0}
   ]
}
```

Comment: `db.all` (similar to `db.get`) is returning a Promise; you need to use a callback or a chained `.then(...)`  to retrieve the result. Consider something like [`Promise.all(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) so that you can run both queries and act upon the results when they've both completed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: thank you @TylerRoper 
I tried Promise all as in the link I got this error
```
TypeError: [object Object] is not iterable
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
```

Thank you @AluanHaddad
I have tried several ones in the link you have sent me
several return empty and several return errors

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by adding async

```js
app.get('/group/:groupId', async (req, res, next) => {

    const members= await db.all('SELECT name,active FROM members WHERE groupId = ?;', req.params.groupId).then();

    return db.get('SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groups.id = ?;',req.params.groupId)
     .then(group =>  res.json({
         group.name,
         members:members
        }))
        .catch(next);
});
```

thanks to all who tried to help